# What are the issues with checking out a git repo to a OneDrive folder?

Tags: git, onedrive

I've checked out a git repo into a OneDrive folder.  The git repo contains some `*.docx` and `*.pptx` files (which aren't mine!), as well as code.

I've noticed that running `git status` shows that the Office documents have changed (even though I've not even opened them). I assume this is a consequence of storing them in OneDrive, but I'm curious to know *what* OneDrive is doing to make git think that the Office docs have changed, but the plain text files haven't (and perhaps Dropbox would do this too).

Are there any other consequences of checking out a git repo into a OneDrive folder that I should know about?

Comment: It could be anything. Assuming that docx and pptx are binary files anything could have changed and the whole file would look different

Comment: @evolutionxbox - I thought *.{office}x files were just a collection of zipped up xml files, but happy to corrected on that! But yes, I know that changing _anything_ would change the file, but I was trying to find out _what_ actually is likely to have changed. Can OneDrive edit metadata of files (and specifically only of Office files)? Or is something else going on?

Comment: what does git tell you changed?

Comment: Ah, it tries to change some permissions and associated metadata...

Comment: Ah that makes sense. Remember git only remembers executable permissions.

Comment: Oh, I didn't know that! I'm not massively experienced with git :)